# rails sprockets include_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

so here is my problem

sprocket defines these directives

```
include
require_directory
require_tree
require_self
depend_on
stub
```

so what I miss is an `include_tree` directive to include all javascript sources (placed in another directory) in one file!

what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your js files are in the directory `lib/assets/your_library/yourfiles.js` (notice , that it should be an assets directory). You just have to create an index file , named index.js ( it is a manifest file too) and insert a directive like this :

```
//= require_tree .
```

(or files you wish to be included)

After that , in your `application.js` insert :

```
//= require your_library
```

More about using index files in asset-pipeline can be found in [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).

Comment: I know how the require_tree and require works. I want include not require for example if I have directory that keeps 100 directories within 100 js files I want to have 1 JS file from that not 100*100 included js-s in `head`

Comment: Just `//= require your_js_dir/your_single_js` (with no prefix) should work fine , in case that it is an pipeline managed directory .

Comment: I guess I could not understand your idea : you'd like to merge the js content from 100s dirs with 100 files each in one file ? This is what the `assets:precompile` task does in `production` . You want it in development too?

Comment: You can issue `rake assets:precompile` and all your required in manifest files will be compressed and placed in `public/assets/application.js` . Remember to repeat the task every time you change a js file . Just curious , what is the goal?

Comment: the goal is kind of silly. If there was include I wondered why there wasn't include_tree